# Windows 11 Android Subsystem: excessive disk utilization after startup

Tags: android, wsl-2, windows-11

I am able to startup and use Windows 11 Android Subsystem to run Android applications (Windows 11 Version 22H2).  However, after I first boot to the Windows 11 desktop and start any Android application, there is constant disk writes to the below file for approximately an hour (per Windows Performance monitor)... even though I am concurrently able to use any Android app without any noticeable lag.  My concern is my C: drive is an SSD; which wears down over time.

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForAndroid_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\userdata.vhdx`

[image]

I saw some posts online that suggest creating the below config file with the respective configuration (or similar).  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have any effect on the disk usage.  It still takes approximately an hour of extended disk writes to `userdata.vhdx`

NOTE:  I currently have 32GB of RAM and 66% free/available physical memory (even with the configuration file settings below); with an 8-core CPU;

```
[wsl2]
memory=10GB
processors=8
kernelCommandLine="sysctl.vm.swappiness=10"
```

Comment: are you sure `WSL2` settings are applied for `WSA`? I'm also having this exact issue, and Android doesn't seem to be running in the WSL, at least it's not in the list of installed distributives.

Comment: I am also having this issue. Out of a sudden I got temperature warning from CrystalDiskInfo and found my SSD heating up to 61 degrees. Then found that there is a high usage writing into userdata.vhdx.

Comment: @RickyMo if you figure out how to stop it from doing this, can you please post here?  I still can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Neither do I. Though I think this question is not suitable on stackoverflow. Maybe try asking in https://superuser.com/